# Translate XML with XSLT groupby

Tags: xslt

I've following XML and I'm trying to translate it using XSLT to another format which is mentioned below. Something is wrong with the XSLT code

```
<resultSet>
<Record>
<OrderID>50321523</OrderID>
<AttributeName>Color</AttributeName>
<AttributeValue>Matt-Light-Brown</AttributeValue>
</Record>
<Record>
<OrderID>50321523</OrderID>
<AttributeName>Size</AttributeName>
<AttributeValue>43.0-18</AttributeValue>
</Record>
<Record>
<OrderID>50321513</OrderID>
<AttributeName>Color</AttributeName>
<AttributeValue>Matt-Light-Brown</AttributeValue>
</Record>
<Record>
<OrderID>50321513</OrderID>
<AttributeName>Size</AttributeName>
<AttributeValue>43.0-18</AttributeValue>
</Record>
</resultSet>
```

Target XML:

```
<Record>
<Orders>
<OrderID>50321523</OrderID>
<Color>Matt-Light-Brown</Color>
<Size>43.0-18</Size>
</Orders>
<Orders>
<OrderID>50321513</OrderID>
<Color>Matt-Light-Brown</Color>
<Size>43.0-18</Size>
</Orders>
</Record>
```

Below is the XSLT code that i'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>    
  <xsl:key name="groups" match="/resultSet/Record" use="OrderID" />

  <xsl:template match="/Record">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', OrderID)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Record">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', OrderID)">
<xsl:element name="{AttributeName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="AttributeValue"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this XSLT is not working as expected. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0, why are you trying to use Muenchian grouping instead of the built-in `xsl:for-each-group`? -- P.S. Offhand, your 1st template needs to be `<xsl:template match="/resultSet">`. Your 2nd template doesn't look right either.

Comment: I'm new to XSLT and I've tried for-each group as well. But didn't work out for me. So, I've explored this option. Now after making changes that you suggested, got below output. But still not as expected.
<Color>Matt-Light-Brown</Color>
<Size>43.0-18</Size>
<Color>Matt-Light-Brown</Color>
<Size>43.0-18</Size>
Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your first template should be matching `resultSet`. Doing `/Record` would only match anything if `Record` was the the root element, which is not the case.

Additionally, your second template is missing a closing `</xsl:element>`, although this might be a typo. But, in anycase, you still need to add the creation of an `Orders` element, and copy the existing `OrderID`.

Try this XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>    

  <xsl:key name="groups" match="Record" use="OrderID" />

  <xsl:template match="/resultSet">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', OrderID)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <Orders>
      <xsl:copy-of select="OrderID" />
      <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', OrderID)">
        <xsl:element name="{AttributeName}">
          <xsl:value-of select="AttributeValue"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Orders>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, there is not need to use the full path to the element in the match of an `xsl:key` if you want to match all of them anywhere.

Note, if you could use XSLT 2.0 (and that means using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0. You can't just change the version number to 2.0 and expect it to work if your XSLT processor only supports XSLT 1.0) you would write it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>    

  <xsl:template match="/resultSet">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="OrderID">
      <Orders>
        <xsl:copy-of select="OrderID" />
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <xsl:element name="{AttributeName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="AttributeValue"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Orders>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```